# Get SKU of each product in an order

Tags: php, pdf, magento-1.9

I have a custom `Shipment.php` file that gives me a custom shipment pdf. The main changes to the code are layout changes. The products still render as usual ie with product sku, quantity and name and custom options such as size and colour. However, I need to get the SKU for each product in each shipment so I can create a barcode for each item. I have code for the barcode that works, I just can't retrieve the SKU. The code from `Default.php` doesn't work for this. The barcode php is below and has been tested with an example of a product SKU from magento. I just need to automatically get all SKUs in a shipment and create barcodes for each

Barcode php:

```
//SKU Barcode
$sku = msj013;
$newSku = strtoupper($sku);
$barcodeConfig = array(
   'drawText' => false,
   'text' => $newSku
);
$rendererConfig = array(
   'verticalPosition' => 'middle',
   'moduleSize' => 0.5
);
            // create dummy Zend_Pdf object, which just stores the current page, so that we can pass it in
            // Zend_Barcode_Renderer_Pdf->setResource()
            $pdf = new Zend_Pdf();
            $pdf->pages[] = $page;
            // @var $renderer Zend_Barcode_Renderer_Pdf 
            $renderer = Zend_Barcode::factory('code39', 'pdf', $barcodeConfig, $rendererConfig)->setResource($pdf, 0);
            // calculate left offset so that barcode is printed on the right with a little margin
            //$leftOffset = $page->getWidth() - $renderer->getBarcode()->getWidth(true) * $renderer->getModuleSize() - 10;
            //$renderer->setLeftOffset($leftOffset);
            $renderer->draw();
            //End SKU Barcode
```

Comment: please attach the code what you are trying and share the problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution! I placed the above barcode PHP inside this `foreach loop`. A barcode is now created for each product inside the any particular order.

```
foreach($shipment->getAllItems() as $item){
    $sku = $item->getSku();
    /*Barcode PHP here*/
}
```

This allows you to insert barcodes into a custom Packing slip PDF module for each product in the order the slip is being printed for!